# How to exchange rectangular arrays via HTTP efficiently and without tightly coupling requesters to responders?

Tags: design, architecture, rest, data-structures, performance

Suppose a user defines input arrays on a JavaScript frontend. These are sent to a Python  backend via the REST API. The backend computes a  result for every combination of each array's elements. It then replies with a JSON file containing the results.

Here's a toy example with  two inputs. The first has five types of oranges, and the second, ten storage durations for apples.  The backend computes a "taste index" or whatever for each input combination used in a fruit salad.

[image]

**Question:** How to decrease response times without tight frontend/backend  coupling and excess complexity?

***Option 0:*** We could have requests with  5 types and 10 durations, ie, 15 elements in total. The response would contain a 50 by 3 matrix listing each input/output combination,  so 150 elements in total. Here's the start of this matrix:

[image]

In my actual app this approach is painfully slow due to bandwidth constraints: ie, large data volumes being sent. The app has 5-8 inputs with 2-1000 elements each. Each input element can be a string, number or a large data structure, whereas  results are always double-precision numbers. It's an Angular 9/Electron Desktop app with a Python 3.8 Flask/Celery parallelised backend.

***Option 1*** Requests in my current solution are as above but a reply only contains a list of 50 results. That is, I only send the Result column from the above table.  Indeed, suppose the backend computes the results in nested loops like so:

```py
results = [ ]
for orange in oranges:
    for apple in apples:
        results.append(compute(apple, orange))
```

Then the frontend could map the index of each result back to the original input levels, eg, to produce a plot. So there's no need to replicate the inputs in an HTTP response.

This approach has reduced the response times between  5 and 20 folds, depending on the problem size.  However, it does bring   extra coupling between the frontend and the backend. The frontend now needs to know the exact order in which the backend processed the inputs. This also constrains backend implementations, eg by requiring one big multi-loop method instead of several smaller methods. It's also proven error-prone in use-cases with many inputs.

Could there be another solution, somewhat less performant but with a cleaner design?

I've also tried splitting up input array between requests so as to reduce the load per request/response cycle. However this appeared too complicated: need to re-assemble results, and so on.  My internet search has found only remotely related references, such as this [SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176093/how-to-reduce-tight-coupling-between-two-data-sources), although I might have used the wrong search terms.

Comment: its unclear what the problem is. is the response slow due to its size vs bandwidth, or due to cpu constraints on the back end? why is one data format smaller than the other?

Comment: why not return the data as multi dimentioned array as shown in the picture

Comment: how does the front end plot 8 dimensional data?

Comment: @Ewan The backend computations are very fast. So it's mainly the bandwidth constraint. Sometimes it took 20-30 minutes or froze. The first format returns 150 data points in rows back to the Frontend  (Apple, Orange, Result). The second format only returns 50 data points (Result.)

Comment: Not returning a multi-D array because of JSON format. That's a good point though. Maybe it's a good compromise between Solution 0 and 1: a bit larger size but preserved inputs/outputs mapping.

Comment: To plot 8D data I use parallel coordinates plots, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates. The main question is about design. Without capacity constraints, I'd put eg a UUID to each result or use Solution 0. But now the return data is detached from original inputs, so it's possible to break the inputs - outputs mapping. Also, I'm limited on what to implement on the backend.

Comment: you can do staggered arrays in json [[],[]] but with your shear volume of data you are in trouble regardless of format

Comment: That's reassuring! Wouldn't I still need a Cartesian product of input level to index each JSON array?

Comment: You could send the 'rows' and 'columns' as a second object

Comment: although, I would send the parralell line data. You could then stream it one line at time draw while dwnloadng

Comment: That's a good idea! Could also look cool, like gradually appearing plot. Hopefully, the extra bookkeeping of split responses won't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Actually, what if the backend sends back some sort of specification of how to decode the results, something like a index2subscript function in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you'd want to singe single indexing instead of two independent indices. I.e. identify each cell with a unique identifier (its values does not matter, it may be based on indices of rows and columns with a simple arithmetic transform or could be a hash, the order of cells in queries/replied then does not matter and they can be updated separately asynchronously).

In summary transform the 2D problem in a 1D problem with a single hash. Then you can decouple the work to the server and even allow multiple servers to do the job needed for each cell. This changes the nature of the problem in separate problems:

- a single set for "types of ranges" (no need to duplicate these values, you'll eventually associate an ordered index or unorderd hash value for each)
- a single set for "prices of apples" (same remark, transmitted separately)
- a single set of cells (each one with its identifying hash) for computing the "taste index" (this can be any kind of computing, as you seem to just give pseudo-examples and not actual use cases)

You can then bind the client and server(s) with more freedom and optimize what needs to be synchronized with network requests (it may be useful as well for the server and client to share a common session identifier for each client that will be part of the hash built for each element of the 3 sets above, so that you can as well distribute the competing clients on the available servers, which may change dynamically or on demand).

Note that the separation between "server(s)" and "client(s)" is artificial. The server may just do nothing else than being a coordinator or communication proxy between the client(s) in a peer-to-peer system. The actual work being done only by the clients accessible via this server, and interacting asynchronously (possibly the work on each "cell" is actually performed by humans, you cannot expect that the whole "grid" of tasks will be performed in any orderly way; as well there may be restrictions/policies about how each client can interact and influence the work or result of each task or "cell" of your grid).

Finally the representation of the division of tasks in a 2D grid is possibly artificial and does not make sense (there may be spans and cells sharing their tasks or results at random places in that "grid", or the grid may just be an aggregate showing a part only of the data which may be structured completely differently (e.g. a hierarchic tree, or many more axis) and some cells may have no meaning (no task to do, no valid input, no valid result to show, no client interested on working to "fix" that).

Comment: That looks like a good approach. So the server would send a request with an Oranges vector `[A,B,...,D]`, an Apples vector `[10, 20, ..., 100]` and a "hash" vector, eg with indices `[{0,0}, {0, 1}, ...,{4, 9}]`. The response would have rows such as  `{0,0}, 0.12` and `{0,1}, 1.38`. Is that right? If not, do you mind putting a couple  examples?

Comment: that's the principle. but {0,0} could be a single unique hash, a single integer (e.g. you interleave the bits in each indice: if your index in Oranges is 16-bit and the index in Apples is 16-bit, interleaving would be 32-bit. If the indexes in Oranges and Vectors have an upper bound, you can just perform basic arithmetic (i*sizeof(Oranges)+j) which is faster than interleaving

Comment: it's up to you to create your suitable "hash" function